# How can I make inner border using CSS3?

Tags: css

How can I make an inner border using CSS3?

That is, instead of the border extending outwards from the active/padding area of the element, it extends inwards, overlapping its contents?

I'd appreciate it if it could be done with a minimum of CSS rules, if it is possible at all.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "inner border"? Use an image if you need to.

Comment: Could you define 'too many'? What criteria/restrictions are you working under?

Comment: @David Thomas: You would have to ask the user who edited this question. The original question said "multiple CSS", and I have no idea how the editor interpreted that phrase.

Answer (score 22):

Try using the box-shadow (and vendor specific subsets).
For example:

```
-moz-box-shadow: inset #B3B3B3 0 -1px 0 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset #B3B3B3 0 -1px 0 0;
box-shadow: inset #B3B3B3 0 -1px 0 0;
```

Comment: Am trying to do the same thing and this works perfectly, thanks.