# Is it possible to make a border 2px in from the containing box?

Tags: css

This is what I mean:

[image]

I want to put a border 2px in from the containing box. Is this possible using only CSS?

Comment: Create a child div inside the containing box.  I tend to use class names like: "container-inner-wrapper".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way, using [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements):

http://jsfiddle.net/1x2chmee/1/

```
.box {   
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: orange;
    position: relative;
    padding: 16px;
}

.box:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    top: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

This method is a bit verbose, but it is well-supported by browsers and flexible.

Another example with a few more options: http://jsfiddle.net/1x2chmee/2/

Comment: Aah was answering the same.. just a note that `padding` on `.box` isn't required..

Comment: @Mr.Alien - agreed, I just added the padding so show that independent styling of the box is possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the CSS `outline` property:

```
.yourDiv {
   height:300px;
   width:500px;
   background-color: #E9967A;
   outline-style: solid;
   outline-offset: -10px;
   outline-width: 3px;
   outline-color: #fff;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/H7KdA/39/

---

More info about this CSS property: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp

---

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=outline

**Edit**: IE9 and IE10 don't support `outline-offset`:

Comment: ummm support will be an issue here.. its better to stick with positioning but nice alternative..

Comment: IE8+ supports this, same as css `:after` pseudo element.

Comment: I already accepted an answer but this one is nice too. I'll keep this in mind for the future. Thank you.

Comment: IE9 and IE10 don't support it. IE8 does. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=outline (click *Known Issues*)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="lol">   <span class="title">This is a title</span> </div>

.lol{
  width: 300px;
  height:200px;
  background: #ff8800;
  position: relative;
}

.lol:after{
  content:'';
  width: 280px;
  height:180px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin:auto;
  border:3px solid #fff;
}

.title{
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding-top: 20%;
}
```

[See it here](http://codepen.io/e6z6a6z/pen/mbzkh)

Answer (score -1):

You can use specific CSS3 box-shadow rules.

```
-moz-box-shadow: inset #B3B3B3 0 -1px 0 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset #B3B3B3 0 -1px 0 0;
box-shadow: inset #B3B3B3 0 -1px 0 0;
```

original post: [How can I make inner border using CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11380212/how-can-i-make-inner-border-using-css3)

Comment: This is the rule that I've been fiddling with. Here I used your code to create a box but I couldn't get the border to show up: http://jsfiddle.net/a0xmtewu/